# need with identifying the meaning of a nested for loops in a function that i found

Tags: python, function, nested-loops, chess

I happen to come upon a function that takes a nxn matrix of ones and converting it to ones and zeros one after the other.
I wanted to know how those nested loops work, why we use nested for loops, why we type
(0, mat.shape[0], 2), why we have '1' in the start of the second nested for loop and what is that '2' in the end of every for loop.
the function is:

```
import numpy as np


def chess_board(n):
    mat = np.ones((n, n))
    for i in range(0, mat.shape[0], 2):
        for j in range(0, mat.shape[1], 2):
            mat[i, j] = 0
    for i in range(1, mat.shape[0], 2):
        for j in range(1, mat.shape[0], 2):
            mat[i, j] = 0

    print(mat)


chess_board(n=5)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, sorry but these are things you come to know when you start learning from the inch of the topic. So even if someone explains it's just that you come to know these but it's not the way to learn a language. So I suggest you to go through online course or a book.

Answer (score 0):

So `mat.shape` is going to provide the dimensions of your matrix. Since the matrix is 5x5, there's actually no point in doing that since both of those values will be 5.

The 1 is because we need to offset each row and column by 1. So imagine that the topmost point (0,0) is a 0 on the chess board. If we offset both row and column by 1, we get (1,1), which is along the same diagonal. And diagonals along a chess board have the same color (which equals the same value - 0 or 1).

The 2 is because we want every other square to be the same color/value. So if (0,0) is white, (0,1) is black and then (0,2) is white again. The 2 is the "step" argument in the range function. So range(0, 11, 2) will product 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10

Answer (score 0):

Just to make a quick and brief note :

=> shape[0] : no of rows

=> shape[1] : no of columns

=> That 2 just makes i and j jump 2 steps in every iteration. Like i += 2 / j += 2